# How to prevent spam when using websocket-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, websocket

Consider the following to implement tic-tac-toe:

One player sends a move by triggering an event on the main dispatcher.

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');

var channel = dispatcher.subscribe_private('private_game');
channel.bind('new_move', function(move) {
  // received new move, process it
});

// later on when we want to send a move to the server we run the following code
var move = {
  square: ...;
}
dispatcher.trigger('move', move);
```

On the server the controller can verify that the user is authorized for that specific game of tic-tac-toe. And then it can broadcast the move to both players.

```
class TicTacToeController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def move
    # code to verify the move is valid and save to database
    ...

    # broadcast move to all players
    WebsocketRails[:private_game].trigger(:new_move, message)

  end
end
```

But there is nothing to enforce that the client sends messages only using the main dispatcher. The 'private_game' channel is suppose to be used only by the server for broadcasting moves. But a hostile client could send random data on it with

```
channel.trigger('new_move', randomdata);
```

Since channel events do not go through the Event Router and thus don't go through a Controller action, there is nothing on the server side to filter out the random spam.

Is there a way to stop random data spam on the server? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to use websocket-rails?

Comment: One strategy I considered was to use randomized per-client channels for server-originated messages.  So you have the main channel that you use for client -> server, then for server -> client, use a channel like "game-#{game.id}-#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}".  You'll need to tell the client the random channel during the initial setup.  I can expand into a proper answer if this suggestion is interesting.

Comment: @DaveS. I would be interested in seeing an example. Is the necessity to do all of that a sign of a missing feature in the WebSocket-Rails gem?

Comment: In my particular case I didn't end up needing it (so no example readily available).  Also in my case I was using juggernaut, not websocket-rails, so it may not be directly relevant.  Just throwing out the idea in case it inspires you to find an indirect solution.

Comment: Author of the WebsocketRails gem here... This is definitely a missing feature in the gem. I have never personally used channels for this scenario so I hadn't considered providing an authorization layer within the channel system that would allow you to screen out malicious messages. I would like to include this functionality as it seems quite useful. Please open an issue on the issue tracker so I can put it on the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could handle this now before the Gem is updated to support this better would be to use a separate private channel for each user.

#### Example

- Game Starts

  1. User A connects to private channel named `user_a_incoming_moves`
  2. User B connects to private channel named `user_b_incoming_moves`

When user B makes a move, you broadcast that on the `user_a_incoming_moves` private channel that only User A is connected to.

When user A makes a move, you broadcast that on the `user_b_incoming_moves` channel that only User B is connected to.

This would prevent anyone from being able to send malicious moves through.

You can read more about private channels in the [Private Channel Wiki](https://github.com/DanKnox/websocket-rails/wiki/Using-Private-Channels).

Comment: Just noticed you are already using private channels in your original example. I guess I should have just kept my answer to "use a separate channel for each user". Sorry for the redundancy.